# Is there a statistical model for the problem I want to solve?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, modeling

I have two time series features, $A$ and $B$: both returns. When $A$ is at 0 (as it is for the vast majority of the dates), you cannot say anything about $B$; it's just noise. However, when $A$ increases, $B$ increases (usually with a day lag) and similarly, when $A$ decreases, $B$ decreases. (I also observed the lag through a Granger Causality test in which the p value is $\approx .001$).
I'd like to find a way to describe/model this relation effectively. Any advice is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: There isn't enough information to provide you with a model that uniquely matches your description. But there are certainly are models that match what you're describing.

Comment: What kind of features are you referring to?

Comment: @Ute the features are returns

Comment: @Galen could you provide their names? Thanks :)

Comment: @Bepop I cannot. The set of such models is unbounded and has elements that are not named. Therefore naming them is not a reasonable request. Here is an example family of models which can exhibit the criteria you mentioned above: [VAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression).